# JDialog setVisible

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have two classes: class jDialog and JFrame

When I click a button in JFrame it calls jDialog class and gets the text on the the textfield inside jDialog and sets it to another variable.
Here's the pseudo code

```
class JFrame {
  private jDialog jd;
  private JButton b;

  public JFrame(){

  b actionListener {
    jd = new jDialog();
    jd.setModal(true);
    jd.setVisible(true);

    String someString = jd.getString();

    checkIfExists(someString);
   }
     }
       }

 public void checkIfExists(String someString){

    if(someString exists) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"String exists);
       jd.setVisible(true);

    } else {
        save someString
        jd.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
```

---

```
 class jDialog {
 private JButton a;
 private String s = "";  
 private JTextField t;

   public jDialog{

     a actionListener {
     s = t.getText();
      setVisible(false);
     }
        }

   public String getString() {
   return s;
   }
}
```

When I enter a string that exists, it prompts the JOptionPane that it is existing but the program flows only once. When I try to edit the textfield, it doesn't go back to the 'checking' of the string if it's existing, instead, the flow stops on 'setVisible(false)' on 'a actionListener' in 'jDialog class' I tracked it using system.out. ( same applies for !exists, it saves only once and when I try saving another non-existent string, It stops )

Any idea how to keep the jDialog running? 
I only use setVisible() to hide it, not dispose();

Comment: Offer the user a `JFileChooser` instead.  And use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: i'm using a mysql database

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to edit the textfield, it doesn't go back to the 'checking' of the string if it's existing

That's because the `checkIfExists(someString)` is done in the `b` listener which instantiate a new `jDialog()`, immediately get the string in the field and perform the check.

You should instantiate only one `jDialog` (in the `JFrame` code):

```
class JFrame {
    private jDialog jd = new jDialog();
```

In the `b` listener set visible the `jd` object (and eventually reset the content of the `JTextField`):

```
b actionListener {
    jd.setVisible(true);
```

Perform the check in the `a` listener (in the `jDialog` class):

```
a actionListener {
    checkIfExists(t.getText());
    setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. I need to call - " String someString = jd.getString();
    checkIfExists(someString);" somehow

Comment: I have just edited my answer in order to show you how to implement the code in the right way.